# How to do an action in a contract to transfer tokens to other user accounts without adding permission in dawn4.0?

Tags: smart-contract

How to do an action in a contract to transfer tokens to other user accounts without adding permission?
Actually, in dawn3.0 i can use the function like this below,
but in dawn 4.0 it doesn't work

```
        action(
            permission_level{ lender, N(active) },
            N(eosio.eos), N(transfer),
            std::make_tuple(lender, _self, shouldback,std::string(""))
        ).send();
```

Comment: What do you mean with “without permission”? If any contract could just take money out of you would be very problematic. What are you trying to accomplish exactly ? Maybe you should start the other way around and start the interaction by making the user transfer money to the contract account ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. actually , i want to create a contract and it  could pay back the tokens to the other user account in a certain time.  “without permission”, i mean the the account related to the contract can have no private key to do such payment action .  only in this way, i can do some transaction automatically.

Comment: Yeah, so what you should do is make the user transfer tokens to the contract, and then as the contract gets notified of the transfer (see the exchange contract on https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/f242db506432c539aa29bd3d2c8dbb3618df30c1/contracts/exchange/exchange.cpp#L211) do what you need. You may need to make it two steps also (first the user "prepares" the transaction calling your contract, then transfers). Then, as the money will be in the contract's account, it can perfectly fire a transfer from its own account back to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, it's very useful of me.

Comment: @ArielScarpinelli could you please give me some hint about contract's notification? I can not find relate document about notification, I'm so confused about this concept.

Comment: I don't know if there is much documentation about notifications. 
There is the `require_recipient` method in the notification sending ocntract (which in this case is eosio.token which already does it) and then you receive a method call in your contract with the transaction information (look at the `on` methods in the exchange contract code).
What's going to happen is that each time tokens are sent to the contract's address, a `transfer` action is going to be fired on it (as the action is called `transfer` in the eosio.token contract)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about outdated  pre-launch code.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:**

The new version (dawn-v4.0.0) improved the permissions system which totally makes sense. If you want to do a `eosio.token::transfer` from your contract you need to add a specific permission for that. Check this:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3013

As Dan said you need to add a permission like this:

```
cleos set account permission your_account active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS7ijWCBmoXBi3CgtK7DJxentZZeTkeUnaSDvyro9dq7Sd1C3dC4","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"your_contract","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p your_account
```

Then you can still use:

```
     action(
        permission_level{ from, N(active) },
        N(eosio.token), N(transfer),
        std::make_tuple(from, _self, quantity, std::string(""))
     ).send();
```

And it totally makes sense because you don't want applications transferring your tokens without your consent. So, by the time that I answered this I didn't know that and I just suggested the use of `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER` because I saw it on the system bandwith routines and thought that it changed, but it's not true. Please stick with the regular `action.send` you just need a permission.

Although, if you want to follow the best practices for the `eosio.token::transfer` check this answer:

https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/361/54

You need to "listen" the `transfer` for your contract and have a balance control for your users, so you can use their tokens for whatever action you need!

**OLD WRONG ANSER:**

Did you try the `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER` already? You need the permission of the `lender` of course.

```
INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(eosio::token, transfer)( N(eosio.token), {payer,N(active)},
                                                 { payer, N(eosio), quant, std::string("buy ram") } );
```

There's no way to execute an action with different permission than the one that you have from the current `action`. Maybe `_self` works but I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you for your help. actually , it's  because of the new permission name in the latest version . and Daniel told me that i should use the new permission name "eosio.code" by using command "cleos set account permission..." and it worked for me. maybe your method is also correct and i will try it later.

Comment: you are right, my answer is not correct at all, I'm in the bed already but tomorrow ill update my answer with the correct steps

Comment: Hi, i tried the new version from Dan to set my permission but i get always the error 3030000 and "unknown key" i tried every key i have but nothing works somehow.

Comment: You will need to change the parameter of your actions from `account_name` to just `name`

Comment: hmmmm changed every paramter as you said but still the same error but still thank you for your help

Comment: problem found!! have older version of eos on my laptop had to change eosio.code with active think i will update my eos version on my laptop

Comment: How would you listen for a transaction?

Comment: for those inline actions, can we check them on blockchain?

Comment: How can I limit the granted amount of tokens?
It seems to me that it can transfer as many tokens as it want ?!
`code`
      std::string memo = std::string("memo");
      asset amount = asset(10 * 10000, symbol("SYS", 4));
      action act = action(
          permission_level(player, "active"_n),
          "eosio.token"_n, "transfer"_n,
          std::make_tuple(player, room, amount, memo));
      act.send();
`code`