# Where is 'INLINE_ACTION_SENDER' macro defined?

Tags: smart-contract, action

I am trying to use INLINE_ACTION_SENDER to use an action from another contract but get the following error.

error: use of undeclared identifier 'INLINE_ACTION_SENDER'

How do I include this macro in my code?

Answer (score 1):

It's in `action.hpp`. Are you in dawn-v4.0.0?

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/dawn-v4.0.0/contracts/eosiolib/action.hpp#L226

This is the definition:

`#define INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(...) BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(INLINE_ACTION_SENDER,__VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)`

And this is an usage example:

```
 INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(eosio::token, transfer)( N(eosio.token), {payer,N(active)},
                                               { payer, N(eosio), quant, std::string("buy ram") } );
```

**EDIT:**

Please check this out before using `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER`: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/320/54

Comment: If anyone could explain the first agrument
   `eosio::token`
that would be great. I am trying to send an action in another contract I created called `helloworld` however when I use `helloworld` as the first argument I get `error: 'helloworld' does not refer to a value`

Comment: @MagicManXpress Good question. Try asking it as a new question so more people see it.

Comment: Check my edit suggestion before using `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER` :P