# require_auth differs from the auth check of INLINE_ACTION_SENDER but how?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, authorization, inline-action

In a contract action I've got the following:

```
require_auth(from);  // NOTICE THIS LINE...
INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(contract, transfer)(
    N(contract),
    {from, N(active)},  // ... AND THIS LINE.
    {from, to, price, memo});
```

When I invoke the action I get:

```
Error 3030002: signatures do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"myaccount","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

Notice that `require_auth(from)` passes but the inline action fails because the authorization `{from, N(active)}` is not present.

**How is that possible? Doesn't `require_auth(from)` in effect check for the authorization `{from, N(active)}`?**

*Methodology*

I'm invoking the action as follows:

```
cleos push action contract action \
  '[ myaccount theiraccount "16 BTC" "DD => PP (C=8)" ]' -p myaccount@active
```

`-p myaccount@active` explicitly provides `myaccount@active` authorization, a fact that I can verify by running, for example, the following...

```
cleos push action contract action \
  '[ myaccount theiraccount "16 BTC" "DD => PP (C=8)" ]' -p essential@active
```

...which causes the `require_auth(from)` to fail as expected...

```
Error 3030001: missing required authority
Ensure that you have the related authority inside your transaction!;
If you are currently using 'cleos push action' command, try to add the relevant authority using -p option.
Error Details:
missing authority of myaccount
```

...because I didn't provide `-p myaccount@active`.

Answer (score 2):

From an answer by Todd Fleming on the EOS Developers Telegram channel:

If user A authorizes an action sent to contract B then that does not imply B can send an action to contract C with A's authorization.

There are two ways to address this. The bad way: have users authorize B to act on their behalf. The good way: contracts can detect when someone transfers tokens to them and act on it.

Comment: I'm not thrilled with this answer because AFAIK the "good" way does not cause the actions to execute as an atomic transaction.

Comment: This make sense since B would act as a middleman in "the bad way".  I see a contract can send a transaction with
    action.send()
. Are there any examples on how to "detect" a transfer to a contract?

Comment: @MagicManXpress You mean like this? https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/364/contract-a-makes-an-inline-call-to-contract-b-how-can-b-determine-that-a-is-the