# Contract A makes an inline call to contract B. How can B determine that A is the one making the call?

Tags: smart-contract, inline-action

Contract A calls an inline action on contract B via `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(...)`.

How can contract B determine that it is being called by contract A?

Comment: That's a good question that I also want to find out, how to see the action sender `account_name`. Before using `INLINE_ACTION_SENDER` please check this out: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/320/54

Comment: @LeoRibeiro Great pointer! I'm using Dawn 3.0 at the moment but for sure that update for Dawn 4.0 looks solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dawn 4.0 at least, when A calls B it does so with an authorization that is specific to itself (generally, `contract@eosio.code`). B can check the authorization.