# Are inline actions are executed in a separate transaction?

Tags: inline-action

As it is stated [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/communication-model) , Inline communication paragraph inline actions are supposed to be executed in the same transaction and inherit authorization from calling action. 
But when i do action.send nodeos gives me

> FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction:
>   3090003 unsatisfied_authorization: provided keys, permissions, and
>   delays do not satisfy declared authorizations

so it looks like it is executed in a separate transaction and with different authorizations.
Same [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/360/require-auth-differs-from-the-auth-check-of-inline-action-sender-but-how?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So is that paragraph is no longer actual? And to inherit authorizations do we have to use deferred transactions?

Comment: What command are you sending? That would help diagnose this I think as the error lists several potential issues that may be cleared up by that.

Comment: i do action.send in the code and error message in subj is displayed in nodeos log

Comment: After all looks like inline action is executed in current transaction, but it definitely doens't inherit authorizations of the parent trans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline actions are part of the same transaction, but their authorizations are separate. This limits abuse. e.g. if I send a `playwith` action to a crypto pet, the pet's contract can't unilaterally take my `eosio.token` tokens.